# Ubuntu Tweak in Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, ubuntu-tweak

I am new, but not all that new to Linux, I run Zorin 5.2 core on one machine. I have an older Milwaukee PC, 2001, XP computer, replaced Foxconn motherboard, original Pentium 4 1.6 GHz processor, upgraded to 1.256 GB of RAM, and 40 GB hard drive. I have installed Lubuntu 12.04 with the LXDE desktop on (XP is gone forever) on this older computer. I really like the OS for its lightness and speed. I am familiar with Ubuntu tweak from Zorin.

I want to know, is it wise to install it on Lubuntu, as it is a lightweight distro? I like tweaks ability on Zorin, but am not sure it would be wise to have on Lubuntu? I already have a tutorial on how to install it on Ubuntu if it is not there. Anyone try it on Lubuntu? Is it worth the trouble, or does it eat up to many resources?

Please let me know if you have any experience with this program in Lubuntu as it is not a default program. I think it would be a great addition to my machine, if it works as well as with Ubuntu and Zorin.

Answer (score 4):

My understanding is that Ubuntu Tweak is principally designed to work with Gnome and has shortcomings (limitations) on LXDE Desktop,. I have no direct experience, just information freely available on the internet.  There are similar questions to this you may want to reference on other [forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1814514)

Comment: Thanks, I could not find that information. This one can be marked problem solved.